# How to click a jQuery Dialog button in TestCafe

Tags: jquery, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I'm creating an automated test using TestCafe and need to dismiss a jQuery Dialog using the "OK" button.

HTML generated by the jQuery Dialog (containing the OK button):

```
<div tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="ui-dialog ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-front ui-dialog-buttons information-dialog" aria-describedby="alert-dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" style="height: auto; width: 300px; top: 325.046px; left: 645.5px;">
<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-corner-all ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix">
<span id="ui-id-2" class="ui-dialog-title">Information</span>
<button type="button" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close" style="display: none;"></button>
</div>
<div id="alert-dialog" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; min-height: 30.062px; max-height: none; height: auto;">Record created. Visit ID is 10008444</div>
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset"><button type="button" class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget">OK</button></div>
</div>
</div>
```

TestCafe script:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

 fixture `My Test`
.page ('http://localhost/');

test('LOBO PS test', async t => {
    await t
        .click('#btnPRSave')
        .click(Selector("button").withText("OK"));
});
```

The above script will "find" the button at the ".click(Selector..." line, but the cursor hovers over it without clicking. Am I missing a step?

**UPDATE**:

I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gcass/63fbm8ns/8/) to test this further...and it works fine on there. TestCafe script for that is:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

 fixture `My Test`
.page ('https://jsfiddle.net/gcass/63fbm8ns/8/');

test('LOBO PS test', async t => {
    await t
    .switchToIframe('[name="result"]')
    .click(Selector("button").withText("OK"))
});
```

Differences between the jsfiddle and real-world versions are:

1. The fiddle uses an iFrame - probably irrelevant;
2. The real-world dialog appears over a Bootstrap Modal...which I suspect may be relevant.

Comment: Do you have an example website of where this isn't working?

Comment: No, it's a company intranet. I have expanded the code above to show all HTML for the jQuery Dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Turned out to be an IE issue. I ran the same test in Edge and Chrome and it clicked the jQuery Dialog button no problem.